# Tensorflow - batch_normalizaiton layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I try to build some neural networks and I would like to use batch_normalization before activation functions but I have some problems.
I'm not sure if I use these layers correctly.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_width, image_height, image_depth), name='x')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_categories), name='y')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
    phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase')

    layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(filter_size, filter_size, image_depth, num_filters), stddev=0.01))    
    layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(num_filters)))

    layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(filter_size, filter_size, num_filters, num_filters), stddev=0.01))
    layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(num_filters)))

    layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(filter_size, filter_size, num_filters, num_filters*2), stddev=0.01))
    layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(num_filters*2)))

    layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(filter_size, filter_size, num_filters*2, num_categories), stddev=0.01))
    layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(num_categories)))

    x = batch_normalization(x, training=phase)

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, layer1_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + layer1_biases
    conv = batch_normalization(conv, training=phase)
    conv = tf.nn.elu(conv)

    conv = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv, layer2_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + layer2_biases
    conv = batch_normalization(conv, training=phase)
    conv = tf.nn.elu(conv)

    conv = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv, layer3_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + layer3_biases
    conv = batch_normalization(conv, training=phase)
    conv = tf.nn.elu(conv)

    conv = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv, layer4_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + layer4_biases
    conv = batch_normalization(conv, training=phase)
    conv = tf.nn.elu(conv)

    conv = tf.layers.average_pooling2d(conv, [4, 4], [4, 4])

    shape = conv.get_shape().as_list()
    size = shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]

    conv = tf.reshape(conv, shape=[-1, size])

    y_ = tf.nn.softmax(conv)

    # Loss function
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=conv, labels=y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)

    extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
        train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)


    # Accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, axis=1),
                                               tf.argmax(y, axis=1)),
                                      tf.float32))


epochs = 1
dropout = 0.5

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


    losses = []
    acc = []

    for e in range(epochs):
        print('\nEpoch {}'.format(e+1))
        for b in range(0, len(X_train), batch_size):
            be = min(len(X_train), b + batch_size)
            x_batch = X_train[b: be]
            y_batch = y_train[b: be]

            extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
            l, a, _ = sess.run([loss, accuracy, train_step, extra_update_ops],
                               feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch, keep_prob: dropout, phase: True})
            losses += [l]
            acc += [a]

            print('\r[{:5d}/{:5d}] loss = {}'.format(be, len(X_train), l), end='')

    validation_accuracy = 0
    for b in range(0, len(y_test), batch_size):
        be = min(len(y_test), b + batch_size)
        a = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_test[b: be], y: y_test[b: be], keep_prob: 1, phase: False})
        validation_accuracy += a * (be - b)
    validation_accuracy /= len(y_test)

    training_accuracy = 0
    for b in range(0, len(y_train), batch_size):
        be = min(len(y_train), b + batch_size)
        a = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_train[b: be], y: y_train[b: be], keep_prob: 1, phase: False})
        training_accuracy += a * (be - b)
    training_accuracy /= len(y_train)

plt.plot(losses)
plt.plot(acc)
plt.show()

print('Validation accuracy: {}'.format(validation_accuracy))
print()
print('Training accuracy: {}'.format(training_accuracy))
```

Error :
I don't know why it is saying that I'm not feeding tensor x?

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [16,32,32,3]
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[16,32,32,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a line you're defining `x` as a placeholder

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_width, image_height, image_depth), name='x')
```

some line next, you override the `x` variable with the result of the `batch_normalization` function call

```
x = batch_normalization(x, training=phase)
```

`x` is no longer a `tf.placeholder`, thus when you use it within the `feed_dict` you're not overriding a `tf.placeholder` value, but you're overriding the `tf.Tensor' generated by the`batch_normalization` op.

To solve, you change the line

```
x = batch_normalization(x, training=phase)
```

with

```
x_bn = batch_normalization(x, training=phase)
```

and in the lines that follow replace `x` with `x_bn`.

In that way the placeholder variable `x` wont'  be overridden and your code should run fine.